# Initializing static member variables in constructors error in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-members

i have encountered a problem that is i have defined a static member variable inside a class with access specifier being private but whenever a constructor is called corresponding an object the compiler displays an error "undefined reference to MyObject::count"
here is my class member variable declaration

```
class MyObject
{ private:
        static int count;
  public:
      MyObject()
         {
           count=0;
          }
 };
```

Comment: Do you really want to set the static variable to be zero each time an instance of "MyObject" is created?

Comment: I agree with @Pixelchemist setting the variable to 0 in the class's c'tor seems like the wrong way to go. I think you mean to set it outside the class (in @volerag answer: `int MyObject::count = 0;`)

Comment: The point of static variables is that they exist independently of any instance of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly define `count`, as there is no definition of `count`. You have just **declared** the static variable, you have not **defined** it.

```
class MyObject
{ private:
        static int count;
        MyObject()
        {
           count=0;
        }
 }; 
int MyObject::count = 0; //Explicit definition of static variables.
```

Comment: It's already declared, `int MyObject::count` is a definition.

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of words. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is just declaration of class
class Foo
{
};

//This is definition of class
Foo obj;
```

When you compile your code with just line `static int count;`, compiler will not find definition for static variable. So it will give you an error of 'undefined reference to `MyObject::count'.

Solution:

```
class MyObject
{ 
private:
      static int count;
public:
      MyObject()
      {
          count=0;
      }
 };

int MyObject::count=0;

int main()
{
    MyObject obj;
    return 0;
}
```